# Can I embed html code into a website using page-mod, in a firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Could you point me towards an example of using page-mod so every time a user enters a website like example.com, alongside the actual content of the page, there would be also some other elements such as a javascript widget?
I'm using the add-on builder for my extension so the page-mod module seems the logical way to solve this.
Thanks a lot

Comment: What's the problem with the examples in the [documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-mod.html)?

Comment: well, there are more problems: first i don't understand where the embedded code will go in the page and how to specify that; i don't understand whether the actual content of the page will be modified; and if i must use workers for the content script

Comment: Can you say more about what this JavaScript widget is meant to do. Assuming it doesn't have to execute with chrome privileges (i.e. outside the content sandbox) then you don't need any workers. You can just put the code to modify the page DOM in the contentScript attribute of the pageMod.

Comment: the javascript widget should be an rss feed reader from other websites.

Answer (score 2):

If the code you want to embed will run properly as part of the webpage you are inserting it into, then you just have to use code like the second example in the [documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-mod.html) Wladimir pointed to:

```
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.org",
  contentScriptWhen: 'end',
  contentScript: 'document.body.innerHTML = ' +
                 ' "<h1>Page matches ruleset</h1>";'
});
```

Just put the necessary code in the contentScript property to change the page DOM in whichever want you want (e.g. by inserting a new JS widget).

If for some reason the widget can't run unmodified as part of the page, you'll need to use a worker. For example, let's say it has to pull down data from another website, which would violate cross-site origin policies. In that case, put the code to get the data from that website in your worker. and use messages to request the data from the worker in your content script.

Answer (score 2):

On a tangent, if modifying a page is all you want to do, you could write a small
greasemonkey script instead of creating a full extension.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/